# Wordpress get_posts() fetch next batch of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the get_posts() function to fetch a batch of posts from a custom post type, sorted by ID, modify those posts and then fetch the next batch.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
require_once('wp-load.php');
$temp_list_of_products_array        = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'sale', 'numberposts' => 10 ) );
$temp_list_of_products_array_length = count( $temp_list_of_products_array );

for ($xt = 0; $xt < $temp_list_of_products_array_length; $xt++) {
    $temp_product_id                    = $temp_list_of_products_array[$xt]->ID;
    $temp_product_untranslated_field    = get_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-product-details', true);
    $temp_product_translated_field      = get_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-translated-product-details', true);
    $temp_product_description_language  = 'en';

    if ($temp_product_translated_field == null) {
        $temp_product_translated_contents   = google_translate_text($temp_product_untranslated_field, $temp_product_description_language);
        update_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-translated-product-details', $temp_product_translated_contents);
    } 
    echo $temp_product_id;
}
?>
```

This works great but the problem is that it only loads the first 10 posts ordered by date.

My question is, how do I get the next batch of 10 posts without have a user activated pagination call?

Thanks

Comment: add offset in your get_posts function http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: I've read the documentation but I'm not sure exactly how it works. So if I add 'offset' => 1, does this mean that the code will run from the first post and then each time I call my function, the next 10 posts are loaded?

Comment: Okay I've just added 'offset' => 1 but the posts fetched each time remains the same when I call my function

Answer (score 0):

first get the current page

```
$paged=($query_vars['paged']!=0 ? $query_vars['paged'] : 1);
```

now calculate the offset value

```
$numberposts=10;
$ofdset=$numberposts* ($paged - 1) ;
```

add your code

```
$temp_list_of_products_array = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'sale', 'numberposts' => 10 ,'offset'=>$offset) );
$temp_list_of_products_array_length = count( $temp_list_of_products_array );

for ($xt = 0; $xt < $temp_list_of_products_array_length; $xt++) {
    $temp_product_id                    = $temp_list_of_products_array[$xt]->ID;
    $temp_product_untranslated_field    = get_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-product-details', true);
    $temp_product_translated_field      = get_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-translated-product-details', true);
    $temp_product_description_language  = 'en';

    if ($temp_product_translated_field == null) {
        $temp_product_translated_contents   = google_translate_text($temp_product_untranslated_field, $temp_product_description_language);
        update_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-translated-product-details', $temp_product_translated_contents);
    } 
    echo $temp_product_id;
}
```

add pagination code at bottom of loop 
check this for wordpress pagination with `get_posts` function 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137100/using-pagination-with-get-posts-on-page-type

Comment: When you mention 'add pagination code at bottom of loop', does this mean that this still requires a user to click on a pagination link to proceed to the next batch? 

My script is actually to be run as a cronjob every two minutes, without any user input. Will your suggestion still work for fetching the next batch?

Thanks

Comment: if you used the cronjob  every two min then no need the pagination only calculate  the offset  in cronjob anp pass the offset value in get_posts function it's load the next batch of 10 post

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do I calculate the offset in the cronjob? I thought that you can only enter the time like this in a cronjob */2 * * * *

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `paged` parameter:

```
$current_page = 1; // <-- Modify this to your needs!

$temp_list_of_products_array = get_posts( 
    array( 
        'paged'          => $current_page, 
        'post_type'      => 'sale', 
        'posts_per_page' => 10 
    ) 
);
```

for *paging*.

Comment: I just tried this but I'm still getting the exact posts each time I call my function. I need a way to have the script load the next batch of 10 posts each time it is called, without any user input. It's a cronjob which I run every two minuts

Comment: get_posts has no paged parameter

Comment: `get_posts()` is only a simple wrapper for the `WP_Query()`, so it **supports** the `paged` input parameter @ankurbhadania

Comment: You have to modify the `$current_page` variable. How many posts do you have? Why do you only fetch 10 posts each time, why not increase the `posts_per_page` value? If you're using the *wp-cron* with lot's of posts, you might for example have to store the latest fetched page number in the `wp_options` table @user2028856

Comment: I have about 7000 posts in this custom post type. I can increase it the posts_per_page value to 1000, will this have an effect?

Comment: It depends on the server setup, what makes sense to have as `posts_per_page`. Also if `google_translate_text()` is making some external calls, then it might be slow. So your idea is to have a wp-cron process running every 2 minutes updating 10 posts each time? But what if all posts are translated? Don't you need to check that and only query posts that are untranslated? Then maybe you wouldn't need the paging? I wonder if an alternative approach would be to do it while you update each post?